# Tools for images in a game

Tags: iphone, android

Are there any tutorials , tools for creating background images, other images for an android game or iphone game?

Comment: -1, because this question is way too broad. Please be more specific. What kind of images? Currently the answer to your question is probably: *Any tool that can save to a PNG*

Comment: well I am just naive in graphics for games , so I need a tool where I can create images of any file format, I am sure there will be tools to create images from one file format to PNG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want a good graphics program that is free, try out [Paint.NET](http://www.paint.net/) (Will require Windows or Mono) or [GIMP.](http://www.gimp.org/)